# I have got a problem using if statements for integers in bash on Gnu/Linux

Tags: bash

```bash
#!/bin/bash
echo " This is about my username "
username=$1
if [ "$user_name" -eq 5 ] 
then 
 echo " The user name is right]

elif [ "$user_name" -lt 5]
then 
 echo " The user_name is wrong "
else 
 echo " you need to go back and rethink "
fi
```

Comment: What are you expecting?

Comment: Are you confusing user names, and user IDs?

Comment: I'm trying to pass an argument with numbers

Comment: Have you run shellcheck? : `shellcheck «script_name»`

Comment: @ctrl-alt-delor I just did, its pointing to line 8, I dont know how to pass the -lt argument that will fit. -lt means less than

Comment: The first error is on line 6, some of the rest are follow on errors (ignore them). Fix line 6, then retest (re-run `shellcheck`).

Comment: I just told this web-site to colourise the program. It shows text strings in green. Do you see anything that is not a string in green? Why?

Comment: Consider the 2 commands: `foo 5]` and `foo 5 ]`.  The first receives one argument (the string `5]`).  The second receives 2 arguments (the string `5` and `]`).  Replace `foo` with `[`.  The final argument to the `[` command *must* be the string `]`.  It cannot be the string `5]`.

Comment: If I were the only person voting this would have been closed as "too broad" -- we ask that code have only one problem to a question, but this has several different syntax errors (all of which http://shellcheck.net/ can identify). At minimum, there are missing spaces before `]` arguments to `[`, and strings with missing close quotes, and a variable referred to as `username` in one place and `user_name` in another.

Answer (score 1):

Install and use `shellcheck`.

```
#↳ shellcheck name

In name line 6:
 echo " The user name is right]
 ^-- SC1009: The mentioned syntax error was in this simple command.
      ^-- SC1078: Did you forget to close this double quoted string?


In name line 8:
elif [ "$user_name" -lt 5]
       ^-- SC1079: This is actually an end quote, but due to next char it looks suspect.


In name line 12:
 echo " you need to go back and rethink "
                                        ^-- SC1073: Couldn't parse this double quoted string. Fix to allow more checks.


In name line 13:
fi
  ^-- SC1072: Expected end of double quoted string. Fix any mentioned problems and try again.
```

Also a text editor, that colours you text will have helped you to spot it. In the screen shot below the editor is displaying text strings in red. Do you see anything that is red, but not a text string? Why?
[image]

There are other errors, but hard to spot until you fix the first.

Comment: $ shellcheck myscript
 
Line 8:
elif [ "$user_name" -lt 5]
^-- SC1009 (info): The mentioned syntax error was in this elif clause.
     ^-- SC1073 (error): Couldn't parse this test expression. Fix to allow more checks.
                          ^-- SC1020 (error): You need a space before the ].
                          ^-- SC1072 (error): Missing space before ]. Fix any mentioned problems and try again.

Comment: Yes. the error on line 8 is not a follow on error. However I would still fix the error in line 6 and re-run `shellcheck`.

Comment: #!/bin/bash
echo " This is about my username "
username=$1
if [ "$user_name" -eq 5 ] 
then 
 echo " The user name is right "

elif [ "$user_name" -lt 5]
then 
 echo " The user_name is wrong "
else

Comment: according to `shellcheck` the next error is in line 8. See your earlier comment, the answer is within.

Comment: The error is my representation of username..

Comment: Did you solve the problems?